# Iterate over array of `AnyShape` in `ForEach`

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I am trying to iterate over an array of `AnyShape` in my `View`–which results in the error `Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'AnyShape' conform to 'Hashable'`.

This is my `ObservableObject`:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var shapes: [AnyShape] = [
        .init(Rectangle()),
        .init(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0))
    ]
}
```

And here’s my `View` resulting in the above mentioned error:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(viewModel.shapes, id: \.self) { shape in
            //display the shape
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: You may want to check out "Demystifying SwiftUI" from WWDC for why something like this may not be a good idea. Instead, think about representing the shapes with your own `struct` or `enum` and rendering based on your model.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hint I got I managed to wrap `AnyShape` into my own `struct` like this (which is obvious but I needed some pushing for):

```swift
struct MyShape: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = .init()
    let shape: AnyShape
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let shapes = [
        MyShape(shape: AnyShape(Rectangle())),
        MyShape(shape: AnyShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)))
    ]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(shapes) { shape in
            shape.shape
        }
    }
}
```