# Is AnyShape similar to AnyView, in the sense that I should avoid using it?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Many say that `AnyView` should be avoided when possible, because it can greatly affect the performance of the diffing that SwiftUI does. ([1](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/avoiding-anyview-in-swiftui/), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/t5ahx5/why_do_people_try_to_avoid_using_anyview/)) I understand why that is the case - the types of the views are erased, so SwiftUI cannot easily analyse the structure of the view.

There is also `AnyShape`, which is also a type eraser like `AnyView`. It erases type information, so I wonder if I should also avoid using it. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61511124/5133585), it seems like we can easily avoid it by writing our own wrapper something like this:

```
struct CustomShape: Shape {
    init<S: Shape>(_ wrapped: S) {
        _path = { rect in
            let path = wrapped.path(in: rect)
            return path
        }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return _path(rect)
    }

    private let _path: (CGRect) -> Path
}
```

There is also the possibility that the above is basically how the built-in `AnyShape` is implemented . Before `AnyShape` is available, many people were writing their own wrappers like this, so it is possible that Apple just added it as a built-in type.

In any case, people still use `AnyShape` in a lot of situations. ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088409/5133585), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74755471/5133585)) It seems to me like `AnyShape` isn't being avoided by people as much as `AnyView` is.

Why not? Doesn't SwitUI need to know about the specific types of shapes? Is it just because shapes are much simpler things than `View`s?